# If I have Haste and Tenser's Transformation cast on me at the same time, how many attacks can I make in one turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The *[Tenser's transformation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tensers-transformation)* spell description (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, pg. 168) states:

> You endow yourself with endurance and martial prowess fueled by magic. Until the spell ends, you can’t cast spells, and you gain the following benefits:
>
> [...]
>
> - You can attack twice, instead of once, when you take the Attack action on your turn. You ignore this benefit if you already have a feature, like Extra Attack, that gives you extra attacks.

The description of *[haste](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste)* says:

> Choose a willing creature that you can see within range. Until the spell ends, [...] it gains an additional action on each of its turns. That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

If wizard A casts the spell *Tenser's transformation* on himself and wizard B casts *haste* on A, does this allow A to perform 4 attacks?

In other words: does the fact that *haste* gives an extra single Attack action prevent *Tenser's transformation* from triggering?

Comment: Just remember that a single caster cannot maintain both as they require concentration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Wizard A gets 3 weapon attacks

*Tenser's Transformation* says:

> You can attack twice, instead of once, when you take the Attack action on your turn.

So, when the wizard uses their normal action to Attack, they get to take 2 attacks (per *Tenser's Transformation*).

When they use the special action from *Haste* to take the Attack action again, however, they only get one weapon attack because Haste specifically limits the number of attacks to 1.

> [The hasted creature] gains an additional action on each of its turns. That action can be used [...] to take the Attack (**one weapon attack only**) [...] action.

This is a specific restriction which overrides the number of attacks granted by *Tenser's Transformation* just as it supersedes the same exact ability as granted by Extra Attack.

**Thus, a hasted, tenser-transformed wizard gets three weapon attacks.**

Comment: Rubiksmoose, if a character had Haste and Extra Attack, could they use their standard Attack action to get 2 weapon attacks, and then the haste attraction to get two more attacks, one with a weapon and one without (e.g. a shove)?

Comment: @sharur: You should ask that as a separate question. (My interpretation would be that you can't use your additional action from Haste to shove/grapple at all, as those are special melee attacks, and Haste only lets you use your additional Attack action to make a single weapon attack.)

Comment: @V2Blast: It was actually a request for clarification on Rubiksmoose's answer. It is unclear to me whether they interpreted the restriction on Haste as you did, or as a maximum limit to the number of weapon attacks as opposed to attacks in general, noting that there are non-weapon attack options granted by the attack action.

Comment: I know it was a request for clarification; I mainly meant that the ambiguity seems significant enough that it could stand alone as a distinct question as well. :)